# How to fetch the floating ip of multiple interface on cloud instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, openstack

curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4 will fetch the floating ip for the primary interface eth0. But I want to fetch the secondary interface floating ip.

is there way to fetch the floating ip of eth1 ?

Comment: Have you tried `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/mac/public-ipv4s` (replace **mac** with the actual mac address of the ENI)

Comment: @jellycsc There is no network available

Comment: ' curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data ------------------->
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
hostname
instance-action
instance-id
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
placement/
public-hostname
public-ipv4
public-keys/
reservation-id'